# Enviar mail PHP en formato html

Tags: php

Tengo este programa que realiza perfectamente su función, envía un mail con archivo adjunto desde el formulario y se reciben los datos insertados.
Me gustaría poder enviarlo en formato HTML para darle estilo al mail, tal que así... ¿Como puedo hacerlo mediante mi código PHP?

```
$mensaje = '<html>'.
    '<head><title>Email con HTML</title></head>'.
    '<body><h1>Email con HTML</h1>'.
    'Esto es un email que se envía en el formato HTML'.
    '<hr>'.
    'Enviado por mi programa en PHP'.
    '</body>'.
    '</html>';​
```

```html
<?php
function form_mail($sPara, $sAsunto, $sTexto, $sDe)
{ 
$bHayFicheros = 0; 
$sCabeceraTexto = ""; 
$sAdjuntos = ""; 

if ($sDe)$sCabeceras = "From:".$sDe."\n"; 
else $sCabeceras = ""; 
$sCabeceras .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
foreach ($_POST as $sNombre => $sValor) 
$sTexto = $sTexto."\n".$sNombre." : ".$sValor; 

foreach ($_FILES as $vAdjunto)
{ 
if ($bHayFicheros == 0)
{ 
$bHayFicheros = 1; 
$sCabeceras .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed;"; 
$sCabeceras .= "boundary=\"--_Separador-de-mensajes_--\"\n"; 

$sCabeceraTexto = "----_Separador-de-mensajes_--\n"; 
$sCabeceraTexto .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 
$sCabeceraTexto .= "Content-transfer-encoding: 7BIT\n"; 

$sTexto = $sCabeceraTexto.$sTexto; 
} 

if ($vAdjunto["size"] > 0)
{ 
$sAdjuntos .= "\n\n----_Separador-de-mensajes_--\n"; 
$sAdjuntos .= "Content-type: ".$vAdjunto["type"].";name=\"".$vAdjunto["name"]."\"\n";; 
$sAdjuntos .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64\n"; 
$sAdjuntos .= "Content-disposition: attachment;filename=\"".$vAdjunto["name"]."\"\n\n"; 

$oFichero = fopen($vAdjunto["tmp_name"], 'r'); 
$sContenido = fread($oFichero, filesize($vAdjunto["tmp_name"])); 
$sAdjuntos .= chunk_split(base64_encode($sContenido)); 
fclose($oFichero); 
} 
} 

if ($bHayFicheros) 
$sTexto .= $sAdjuntos."\n\n----_Separador-de-mensajes_----\n"; 
return(mail($sPara, $sAsunto, $sTexto, $sCabeceras)); 
}

// Dirección email 
if (form_mail("info@test.es", "Datos enviados desde la web", $_POST[asunto], $_POST[Email])) 
echo "<script>alert('Se ha enviado correctamente. Revisa tu bandeja de correo. Muchas gracias!')</script>"; 
echo "<script>window.history.go(-1)</script>";
?>​
```

Answer (score 1):

Realmente sólo es una cuestión de cabecera. En vez de:

```
$sCabeceras .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed;";
```

Prueba con, para texto plano:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Y para HTML:

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

En esta línea puedes añadir tu `$mensaje`:

```
$sTexto = $sCabeceraTexto.$sTexto;
```

Quedando algo así:

```
$sTexto = $sCabeceraTexto.$mensaje;
```

Comment: Eso lo tengo claro, lo que no veo claro en que linea insertar $mensaje

Comment: He modificado la respuesta, prueba con eso :)

Comment: Algo se me escapa, he probado así y sigo recibiendo el correo con los datos del formulario de igual manera, y no veo el contenido HTML de test.

Comment: Ahora mismo no me da tiempo a montar una prueba, espero más tarde tener un rato. Entretanto, inténtalo con un ejemplo sencillo, enviando sólo cabecera y cuerpo del mensaje, para después añadir el adjunto. A ver en qué punto falla.